# How can I define a primitive type variable in a rule, in GrGen.NET?

Tags: .net, graph, rule

Is there a way to define a primitive type (integer, string, ...) variable in a rule, e.g. to facilitate/enable attribute calculations?

P.S.: GrGen.NET is a quite popular graph transformation library (check it out on http://grgen.net) based on the .NET-framework. It would be cool if someone could define a Tag for GrGen.NET, I don't have enough reputation :-). Cheers!

Comment: What is this in relation to? Is there something called "booggie", which isn't easily found on Google? Can you provide a link? It's great that you've answered this, but this question needs more to be helpful for future visitors.

Comment: booggie is a graph-grammar implementation that can generate network-like models. I would have generated a tag to cluster booggie-related questions. But, I don't have sufficient score. Maybe, you could help me out?

Comment: Can you provide a link to more information about booggie?

Comment: I recently wrote a journal paper about the underlying technology that you'll find here: http://asmedl.org/getabs/servlet/GetabsServlet?prog=normal&id=JMDEDB000134000002021008000001&idtype=cvips&gifs=yes&ref=no

Comment: No problem. I've also added a bit to the [tag wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/booggie) - you might want to expand on it (try to keep it objective).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you define a primitive type variable in a rule, the key word **var** is crucial.

Do it like this:

```
def var my_int_variable:int;
```

If you want to create a non-primitive variable, e.g. an array, you need to create a variable *by reference* using the keyword **ref** instead of **var**.

```
def ref my_int_variable:array<int>;
```